# compiler won't advance in recursive reversal of singly linked list

Tags: java, recursion, singly-linked-list

I have a recursive static method inside a `SinglyLinkedList` class which runs forever for an undetermined reason. This class is generic and its declaration looks like this:

```
public class SinglyLinkedList<E>{
```

This class has an inner generic class `Node` which looks like this:

```
private static class Node<E> {
    private E element;
    private Node<E> next;

    public Node(E e, Node<E> n) {
        this.element = e;
        this.next = n;
    }

    public E getElement() {
        return this.element;
    }

    public Node<E> getNext() {
        return this.next;
    }

    public void setNext(Node<E> n) {
        this.next = n;
    }
}
```

In addition, the `SinglyLinkedList` class has the following fields:

```
private Node<E> head = null;

private Node<E> tail = null;

private int size = 0;
```

The method I am having trouble with is called `reverse` and its purpose is to reverse the order of a singly linked list in a recursive manner. Here is the code for this method:

```
public static SinglyLinkedList reverse(SinglyLinkedList l) {
    if (l.size < 2) return l;
    Node first = l.removeFirstNode();
    SinglyLinkedList reversed = reverse(l);
    reversed.addLast(first);
    return reversed;
}
```

The `reverse` method uses a non-static method called `removeFirstNode` whose purpose is to remove the first `Node` in the singly linked list and return it:

```
private Node<E> removeFirstNode() {
    if (isEmpty()) return null;
    //Node<E> answer = new Node<>(this.head.getElement(), null);
    Node<E> answer = this.head;
    this.head = this.head.getNext();
    this.size--;
    if (this.size == 0) this.tail = null;
    return answer;
}
```

The `reverse` method also uses a non-static method called `addLast` whose purpose is to add a given `Node` to the end of a singly linked list:

```
private void addLast(Node<E> n) {
    if (isEmpty()) this.head = n;
    else this.tail.setNext(n);
    this.tail = n;
    this.size++;
}
```

The problem is that when I try to run the `reverse` method on a `SinglyLinkedList` of `size` equal to 2 the compiler gets to the line

```
reversed.addLast(first);
```

and then inside the `addLast` method it stops on the line

```
this.tail = n;
```

and runs forever without terminating. If `size` equals 3 or more the compiler gets to the line

```
reversed.addLast(first);
```

and stops there without even entering the `addLast` method. Now if I replace the line

```
Node<E> answer = this.head;
```

with the currently commented-out line

```
Node<E> answer = new Node<>(this.head.getElement(), null);
```

the `reverse` method terminates without any issues. Can anybody explain what is going on here?

**EDIT:** I just realized that the differing behavior for `size` 3 or more is just an artifact of recursion. The real problem is with the case when `size` is equal to 2 and the method inexplicably terminates on the line

```
this.tail = n;
```

**EDIT 2:**

Minimal Code:

```
public class SinglyLinkedList<E>{

private static class Node<E> {
    private E element;
    private Node<E> next;

    public Node(E e, Node<E> n) {
        this.element = e;
        this.next = n;
    }

    public E getElement() {
        return this.element;
    }

    public Node<E> getNext() {
        return this.next;
    }

    public void setNext(Node<E> n) {
        this.next = n;
    }
}

private Node<E> head = null;

private Node<E> tail = null;

private int size = 0;

public SinglyLinkedList() {}

public int size() { return this.size; }

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return this.size == 0;
}

public void addLast(E e) {
    Node<E> newest = new Node<>(e, null);
    if (isEmpty())
        this.head = newest;
    else
        this.tail.setNext(newest);
    this.tail = newest;
    this.size++;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    String output = "";
    if (this.size > 0) {
        Node<E> current_node = head;
        while (current_node != null) {
            output += current_node.getElement();
            if (current_node != tail) output += ", ";
            else output += "\n";
            current_node = current_node.getNext();
        }
    }
    return output;
}

private void addLast(Node<E> n) {
    if (isEmpty()) this.head = n;
    else this.tail.setNext(n);
    this.tail = n;
    this.size++;
}

private Node<E> removeFirstNode() {
    if (isEmpty()) return null;
    //Node<E> answer = new Node<>(this.head.getElement(), null);
    Node<E> answer = this.head;
    this.head = this.head.getNext();
    this.size--;
    if (this.size == 0) this.tail = null;
    return answer;
}

public static SinglyLinkedList reverse(SinglyLinkedList l) {
    if (l.size < 2) return l;
    Node first = l.removeFirstNode();
    SinglyLinkedList reversed = reverse(l);
    reversed.addLast(first);
    return reversed;
}}
```

Test Class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 4;
    SinglyLinkedList<Integer> list = new SinglyLinkedList<>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) list.addLast(i);
    System.out.print(list);
    System.out.print(SinglyLinkedList.reverse(list));
}
```

Comment: Please provide complete code which one can build and debug. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for the idea. Also, you may want to familiarize yourself with a debugger, this kind of short code can be run line by line, and then you will see what happens and how.

Comment: How do you know the JVM 'inexplicably terminates' on a certain line? Are you stepping through in a debugger or something?

Comment: Yes, I am using a debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation of `removeFirstNode()` doesn't unlink the next pointer for the node.

In the original linked list, the first node's next point points to the second node, and the second node's next pointer is null.

In the new list, the first node's next pointer will point to the second node, but the second node's next pointer will point to the first node (which used to be the second node).

Something like this (original list):

```
+---+    +---+
| A |--->| B |--->null
+---+    +---+
```

When reordered becomes this because A's next pointer still points to B:

```
+---+    +---+
| B |--->| A |---+
+---+    +---+   |
  ^              |
  |              |
  +--------------+
```

You could change your `removeFirstNode()` implementation to be something like this:

```
    private Node<E> removeFirstNode() {
        if (isEmpty()) return null;
        Node<E> answer = this.head;
        this.head = this.head.getNext();
        answer.next = null; // Set next ptr to null
        this.size--;
        if (this.size == 0) {
            this.tail = null;
        }
        return answer;
    }
```

The code probably looks like it "stops" because the debugger tries to print out the list using `toString()`, which I imagine traverses the list and never completes because of the loop.

Comment: I believe this is the problem (thus my commented-out solution), but it still has me wondering: isn't this the concept behind a circularly linked list? If so, why would it cause a problem?

Comment: Ah, the while loop in the `toString()` method is causing it. That' it!